# Validating URLs that don't have http

Tags: java, validation, apache-commons, url-validation

I want to validate the website address user input in java side. I have used `org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator` for this, but it needs URLs to start with `http://`, `https://`, or `ftp://`.

However, in my case i want to accept the address just starting with `www.`, like `www.stackoverflow.com`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) object and check if `getScheme()` is empty or null. If so, preprend `"http://"`

Comment: URL websiteUrl = new URL(www.stackoverflow.com); itself throws java.net.MalformedURLException: exception !!

Comment: Is it safe to assume MalformedURLException exception occurs only when No/Unknown protcol is present? so that i can  preprend "http://" in catch block of MalformedURLException ?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up URI and URL. The Java net API is not very intuitive ;) I fixed the answer.